# Calling batch file from Java shows another directory

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying through Java to call a batch file in another folder directory.

```
String cmd = "cmd /c start /wait " + backupFolder + "\\script_encrypt.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```

However, when the batch file runs, it shows me the current directory which the batch is not there, why?.

[image: i]
[image: e]

[image]

Comment: Is the `ecr.bat` file located in the `D:\Testof\Backup` directory? And what does `encrypt_scripts.exe` have to do with the Java code above?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki usually i don't like to show my actual code, for my company privacy anyway ecr.bat is script_encrypt.exe. i have edit my code

Comment: Still confusing. The names in your code snippet, the screenshot from Eclipse debugging and screenshot from Cmd are not matching. 
No need to share secrets. Just create a consistent example outside of your main setup and share this.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki check now is it clearer ?

Comment: @Moudiz: How are you trying to execute it? Are you invoking it from an IDE? And, where do you want the .bat to start from i.e. the exact path?

Comment: @Azeem yes from ide i am debuging. I want the bat to be extract from `test` folder but project is not in test folder

Comment: @Moudiz: In that case, you can add the command to switch to initial path i.e. `cd path` -  path in your case would be the `test` directory. You might want to add the directory structure in your question as well for better responses.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the batch file path and the path called from Java are the same?
According the screenshot from Eclipse and the screenshot from Cmd, they are not matching.

I have done the same, and worked for me.

Comment: well thats my problem , that its not matching.in ide its showing in test backup however the cmd directory showing the current java project. understand me ?

Comment: Yes I know.I did like the same with you did.